# Overfitting in polynomial regression and other concerns

Tags: regression, fitting, overfitting

Given a set of data and training points, suppose we obtain a polynomial regression of the form

$$f(x) = w_0 + w_1 x + \ldots w_n x^n$$

- Is there a rule of thumb as to what order of the polynomial is it
  more likely to overfit? For example, can we say that as the order of the polynomial grow, the likelihood of overfitting increases?
- Also, is it common to observe explosive behavior for higher order
  polynomials? For example, your data is concentrated between range
  $[-5, +5]$. Could the polynomial regression explode to the range of
  say $[-1000, 1000]$ due to the higher order terms $x^n$, the weights,
  and possibly the outliers in the training data?

Comment: If I may: whenever you can, please look at a plot of the data along with your fitted model. "Good" statistical measures do not preclude nonsensical results, cf. Anscombe's quartet.

Comment: Even the saturated model may be an underfit of the true process if there is not enough data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- There is no such rule about specific order polynomials which is agnostic to your dataset. If any such rule existed, I would expect it to be a function of your data or your data generating process - without knowing something about that, it's hard to say. Without saying anything about specific order polynomials, your general statement is right - larger order polynomials are more likely to overfit. As the order of the polynomial increases, so does the variance of the estimator.
- Yes, this is a common issue with higher order polynomials. It is similar in spirit to [Runge's phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon). The common solutions are to find the best order via cross-validation (grid search), or by controlling the size of the coefficients with regularization.