# Polynomial regression has good Mean Squared Error but poor prediction on unseen data

Tags: predictive-models, polynomial, mse

In a dataset, the unseen target value is 2500000000.
In a polynomial regression with degrees from 1 through 7, I have the following results:

`Degree: 1, Mean Squared Error: 410983500.2950994, Predicted: -81178512721.65013`

`Degree: 2, Mean Squared Error: 5829093.43611284, Predicted: -81178512721.65013`

`Degree: 3, Mean Squared Error: 0.006954321149912846, Predicted: -81178512721.65013`

`Degree: 4, Mean Squared Error: 0.9152467870231109, Predicted: -81178512721.65013`

`Degree: 5, Mean Squared Error: 19.06090147224352, Predicted: -81178512721.65013`

`Degree: 6, Mean Squared Error: 8651.727673046189, Predicted: -81178512721.65013`

`Degree: 7, Mean Squared Error: 78583221.21056704, Predicted: -81178512721.65013`

The polynomial regression has the lowest error when degree = 3. But the predicted value is too erroneous. Moreover, in all the degrees, the predicted values remain same and negative. Can anybody throw light on this?

Comment: high degree polynomial regression without regularization is awful :) This has been addressed in some other questions, like this one: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/549012/why-is-the-use-of-high-order-polynomials-for-regression-discouraged

Comment: Can the data be made available?  This apparent numeric instability can probably be fixed with appropriate centering and scaling of the predictor variable.

Comment: @JohnMadden I went to the link you mentioned and found Regression Splines as a solution. I went through an article at https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/03/introduction-regression-splines-python-codes/ and found useful. Thank you.

Comment: @JimB Sorry, the data cannot be made public for proprietary rights. I'll try your method. Thank you.

Comment: The real fix is in the link of @JohnMadden 's comment.  But if you really need polynomials, then centering and scaling should minimize numerical stability issues.  Using orthogonal polynomials will also minimize numerical stability issues.

Comment: @JimB I do not specifically need polynomials, rather best fit. For that, I'll try all the suggestions mentioned.

Comment: "Best fit" means nothing until you describe the space of possible functions you will permit to fit the data.  Otherwise there is a bewilderingly large and varied set of optimal fits.